# Does the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ show all subkeys

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, registry, registrykey

If i open this registry, and read out all subkeys, its different then my registry editor shows.

The way i open the registry and read out all subkeys :

```
//Get all results of the specified registery
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
     foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
     {
         using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(subkey.Name);
         }
     }   
}
```

This gives me the output from all subkeys in this registrykey.

As example i will take one out :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FDCFD759-BA24-F0C8-FE83-43513EE6D443}`

When i check my registry editor. And search this example it isnt in the given location, but it is in :

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FDCFD759-BA24-F0C8-FE83-43513EE6D443}`

So coming to the question .....

Does the registry editor show all subkeys?

If there are any questions about my question or comments, i'd love to hear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "Windows on Windows", and it's by design.

Just like `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`, the `WOW6432Node` key is special. When 32-bit processes try to read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\` they are instead directed into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node` so they they don't try to accidentally do something that is only available for 64-bit processes.

Comment: Because of course you can't expect an program written before 64bit even existed to know to do anything special. Personally, I would have handled this differently, and just added a new `x64` section that you can use for newer processes that should be aware of the distinction.

Answer (score 3):

By default Regedit on a 64-bit Windows machine shows you the [64-bit view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx) of the registry.

32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows sees the 32-bit view by default. These keys are under `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node` in the 64-bit registry.

Uninstall information is stored in 4 places in the registry on a 64-bit machine: Under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` roots in the 64 and 32-bit views.

Applications can decide which view they want to access by using the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag when opening the key.